# Can I inspect `context.store` in any react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'd like to access `context` for the purpose of debugging and learning while working on an app that uses React and react-redux.

You can see Redux's use of the `context` object at this point in time in this video: https://youtu.be/VJ38wSFbM3A?t=13m36s

I have tried:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    console.log("MyComponent context", context); // Just an empty object
  }
  static childContextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
  };
}
```

How can I inspect this `context` object?

Answer (score 1):

If instead of `childContextTypes` I write `contextTypes`, the context object has `store` available and can be inspected.

`childContextTypes` is the API for adding to context, and `contextTypes` is the api for specifying what you want to **consume**.

Answer (score 0):

You can. But then for every component you wish to debug, you have to set up the context handlers just to get access to the store.

A far superior way to debug/inspect your store is to use Redux dev tools.

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension